# Can't understand the output of a program

Tags: c

can anyone tell me why this program is printing 3 as the output or tell the functionality of the program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct st
{
        int a;
        int b;
};
void func(struct st*);

int main()
{
        struct st ab={128,768};
        struct st *pq=&ab;
        func(pq);
        return 0;
}

void func(struct st *p)
{
        char *pt;
        p->a=768;
        p->b=128;
        pt=(char*)p;
        printf("----%d\n",*(++pt));
}
```

Comment: `768`:`0x0300`.

Comment: Had you copied this code from somewhere and asking us why the code isn't working?

Comment: its was an interview question , which someone asked to me yesterday.So not copied from any site(According to me at least).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have stored 768 in first member of struct st, so address at start of struct has 0x00000300(considering 4 bytes of int) in memory, when viewed as little endian stream it will look as 0x00030000

You have stored its pointer in ptr which is char * which now points to value 0x00, ++ptr will point to next value ie 0x03

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I got things now.